# Slow Ubuntu on USB

Tags: usb

I recently did a full install of Ubuntu on a 64 gig Corsair 3.0 USB thumb drive. It takes quite a while to boot up. And once in, it takes a while to get anything done.  For example, I click to open Firefox, a few minutes later Firefox will open. Is this because it is installed on a thumb drive? And would it be better/faster to install it on an external HDD (still using USB).

Edit-The PC I am using is an Asus ROG g752vt. Its an Intel i7-6700, 16 gig of ram, Nvidia GTX 970m. I installed it using virtualbox VM of Ubuntu

Edit 2- I also booted on a computer a school today. I don't know the specs of that computer, all I know is a Dell. It was even slower on that PC than it was on my laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] and post hardware specifications it's the PC you're using. There's a chance the "problem" has to do with something else.

Comment: I find even mechanical 3.0 USBs are a lot faster than 3.0 flash drives running Ubuntu. Small external SSDs are abundant now, and faster than mechanical..I am not sure that any of my installs on USB 3.0 flash actually boot 3.0.